# Find/Iterate through an Android CustomListView, to find selected checkboxes

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have created a custom ListView, and populated with an `ArrayList` of objects. It also has a checkbox, to allow the user to select certain items, and then on a button click do something with them.

**My question is:** How to iterate through the ListView code-side?
I've looked at the docs for ListView but can't find a method that looks as if it iterates through. Do I need to implement this in my `CustomArrayAdapter`??

Comment: Is there a method similar to onListItemClick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. You shoudn't implement nothing from nessesary methods in CustomAdapter.

```
private void ButtonClick() {
    View v;
    CheckBox chBox;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.getCount(); i++) {
        v = myList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        chBox = (chBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);//your xml id value for checkBox.
        if (chBox.isChecked()) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
....
}
```

Comment: Is "myList" the ListView? thanks for the help, this looks like it should work!! :)

Comment: @Swedish Architect, Yes. MyList is ListView.

Answer (score 2):

I would not advice to use Anatol's method as this will create new views for each item. The best way to approach this would be to handle the click of the check box and update your model accordingly. Then you can do something like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = myList.getAdapter();

for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    if (adapter.getItem(i).isChecked()) {
        doSomething();
    } 
}
```

Note that isChecked need to be created in your model class. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Which class is the model class?? thanks for the help!!

Comment: @MobileSam, In my variant we have efficiency problems, in yours we have to write more code and this is more complicated implementation. I think we should think about efficiency only when we have problems.
Despite this your answer is pretty cool and i up voted this.

Comment: I just want to fire this on a button click, then send SMS messages to the people chosen from the list. This looks as if it does that. Thanks!! I'm not too bothered about efficiency, but concerned about writing "neat" code.

Comment: which class is my model class- is it my custom adapter class?? thanks

Comment: Your model is the class that your custom adapter will holds. Your adapter will likely extends ArrayListAdapter which take a type as template.